# Stop the IOS bouncing in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

Im making an application in Xamarin.Form and i am new in Xamarin. In IOS the application bounce when scroll in the top. Is there anyway to stop the scroll bouncing?

I try running a CSS file and did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a dedicated property for this on iOS. This is `AlwaysBounceVertical`. There are also a few related properties to this.

Setting these properties isn't supported directly in Forms though, so you need to create a custom renderer or equal. Have a look at this one:

```
using NoBounceiOS.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView), typeof(NoBounceRenderer))]
namespace NoBounceiOS.iOS
{
    public class NoBounceRenderer : ListViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.AlwaysBounceVertical = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah sort of, it give me a start and I got it working. THX!

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:** in Xamarin.forms for iOS there are some property of UITableView(listview in forms).

```
@property(nonatomic)  BOOL  bounces;                  // default YES. if YES, bounces past edge of content and back again

@property(nonatomic)  BOOL  alwaysBounceVertical;     // default NO. if YES and bounces is YES, even if content is smaller than bounds, allow drag vertically

@property(nonatomic)  BOOL  alwaysBounceHorizontal;   // default NO. if YES and bounces is YES, even if content is smaller than bounds, allow drag horizontally
```

So ,only set `AlwaysBounceVertical` as false will not work.You should set the `bounces`as false.

**Solution:**
As @Gerald Versluis said you can use CustomRenderer.

```
public class MyListViewRenderer:ListViewRenderer
{
    public MyListViewRenderer()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
            Control.Bounces = false;
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: "So ,only set AlwaysBounceVertical as false will not work." I tested it before posting this answer. It works fine :)